# How to remove item from list with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an  output with content like below

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Songs
        <ul>
             <li>
                 Genre
                 <ul>
                     <li>
                         Country
                     </li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>
        Songs
        <ul>
             <li>
                 Genre
                 <ul>
                     <li>
                         Pop
                     </li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please ignore why the content is shown like that. My question is, how can I use jQuery to remove the repeating parents `<li>` and `<ul>` so it will look like this

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Songs
        <ul>
             <li>
                 Genre
                 <ul>
                     <li>
                         Country
                     </li>
                     <li>
                         Pop
                     </li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried unwrap() method, but don't know the logic to put the `<li>` where they should be.

Comment: JQuery doesn't seems to be the good place to do that. You should generate the right content from the server side if this behaviour doesn't eed to be dynamic

Comment: show us your javascript or jquery that you have tried ( if you can share JSFiddle that would be better).

Comment: Wow @undefined's method and the answer below work. Thank you every much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get what I need and re-write it, assuming there is some sort of container around the entire thing just re-write the middle. Code could be cleaner but it works nice.

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li>
        Songs
        <ul>
             <li>
                 Genre
                 <ul>
                     <li>
                         Country
                     </li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>
        Songs
        <ul>
             <li>
                 Genre
                 <ul>
                     <li>
                         Pop
                     </li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
var li='';
$.each($("li:contains('Genre') ul li"), function(i, e){
  item=$(e).children('ul').text().replace(/\n/g,'').trim()||'';
    if (item.length!=0){
        li+='<li>'+item+'</li>';
    };
});

if (li.length!=0){
    var html='<ul><li>Songs<ul><li>Genre<ul>'+li+'</ul></li></ul></li></ul>';
    $('div').html(html);
};
</script>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/886P3/

Comment: what if Songs and Genre are dynamic values ?

Comment: You should have said that in the question :)

Comment: ahh this is extra from what I asked above. :)

Comment: @JackLe No problem, just take anyone of the suggestion from here.. and just post your new requirement as a new question. so that your question may get attention of many other experts..

Answer (score 4):

Try,

```
var uls = $('ul');
uls.first().find('ul:last').append(uls.last().find('li:last'));
uls.first().siblings('ul').remove();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FxVH9/)

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. Can you explain what's going on in the code please ? I'm pretty new to jQuery

Comment: Btw, what if i have more than just 1 main `<ul>` ? It will only append the last `<li>` and ignore those in the middle right ??

Comment: @JackLe yeah that's right, we just written the code which works for static condition not for the dynamic one as you said... :)

Comment: if the content is dynamic, what should I change to make your code work ?